# How do you use a fingerprint to boot LUKS-encrypted Arch Linux?

Tags: linux, arch-linux, grub2, luks, fingerprint

I'm searching for clues on how to use a fingerprint reader to unlock a LUKS-encrypted device.

My hard disk uses `/dev/sda2` (encrypted with LUKS) to start the OS. I don't want to use complex passphrases because it could be forgotten by the users.

How do you use a fingerprint to boot from a LUKS-encrypted device?

Answer (score 0):

You don't.

Biometrics implement authentication by rendering a value which is *sufficiently close* to the reference value. OTOH decryption requires *exactly* the right key.

While you could (in theory) use biometrics to authenticate a user and authorize the retrieval of a key this requires a lot of specialized software and either a network connection to a separate host that runs/stored keys in a retrievable format OR some very specialized hardware built into your local machine. I am not aware of any implementation of such capability (I don't believe TPM/secure bot fully supports this).